# Web app inside iframe change the parent window location

Tags: javascript, html

I have one page where I am using  tag. As a source of this iframe I am passing one external webapp. Now when this app is loading, in its home page it has code which checks whether the app is loading inside frame or in parent window. If it is not in parent window then it is getting the refrence to parent window and change the location in such a way that it display itself in parent window.
Now I dont have control over this web app so I cannnot change it's home page, is there any workaround where I can stop this application to change it's parent window location. Here is the sample code I am using. I cannot give the url of the internal webapp. Before I see the alter msg "test", webapp is changing the location of the parent window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
window.onload = function()
{
    alert('test');
    //frames["my_iframe"].onload = function()
    //{
        //alert("hey");
    //}
    //this also works for me:
    document.getElementById("my_iframe").onload = function()
    {
        alert("hey");
    }
  }
// ]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
Testing iframe....<br>
<iframe name="my_iframe" id="my_iframe" src="http://mywebapp.com" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do what is referred to as XSS or cross site scripting, and is, for obvious reasons, impossible in any modern browser due to security mechanisms.

Comment: All I want to do is, stop the inside webapp to change the location of its parent window.

Comment: I'm afraid you are out of luck. Altering script behavior from another domain is impossible in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This article discuss this question and offers a 'solution', so to speak.

[We Done Been ... Framed!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html)

It's actually about avoid been framed (as the webapp you talk about does) but at the end there seems to be a way to frame any page...